# Arrangements around a table with at least 4 in a row - casework

Tags: probability

Six dogs and six cats are sitting at a circular table at random. Find the probability that there are at least four dogs in a row somewhere in the circle.

My solution: There are $6*5*4*3$ ways to get 4 dogs such that order matters. We can consider this group of four dogs as one supergroup. Then there are 9! permutations of the 8 remaining animals (2 dogs, 6 cats) and 1 supergroup. Then, there are 12! permutations of the 12 animals possible. Therefore the probability would be $(6*5*4*3*9!) \div 12! $ = $3/11$. (I realize that for circular tables, if the seats are not distinguishable, the number of ways to sit around the table would be $11!$. I am approaching it differently for simplicity).

I then tried to do this with casework - where we have 4 dogs together, 5 dogs together, 6 dogs together. Example: for the case of 4 dogs in a row, I tried doing CDDDDC, so that we are guaranteed to have 4 dogs only in a row. With this approach, I get different results no matter what I try. Is my initial answer incorrect? If so, what's the proper way to approach this with casework?

Comment: Your initial answer is not correct. It counts permutations with five or six dogs together multiple times. For example, five dogs ABCDE is counted once with the four dogs ABCD and again with the four dogs BCDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$11!$ arrangements of cats and dogs around the table would be if we named the dogs and the cats.  But, if the cats and dogs are completely interchangeable we can divide by the number of ways to arrange 6 named cats and 6 named dogs.   $\frac {11!}{6!6!} = \frac {1}{12} {12\choose 6} = 77$

We have our supergroup of $4$ dogs bookended by $2$ cats to give us the number of ways that exactly 4 dogs will be next to each other.  Our ability to rotate the table means we can always count from the beginning of the supergroup.  Then there are ${6\choose 2}$ ways to seat the remaining animals.

${6\choose 2} + {5\choose 1} + {4\choose 0}$ ways to arrange c's and d's with 4 or more d's next to each other.

$\frac {21}{77} = \frac  {3}{11}$ matching with your other method.