# Probability independent of distinction between objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence

My problem is a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751974/arrangements-around-a-table-with-at-least-4-in-a-row-casework).

I initially solved it assuming that all cats and dogs are distinct. Then I went through the solution, only to realise that the exact same answer as mine had been arrived at, by considering each cat indistinguishable from the other and the same for the dogs.

---

**My Answer (Distinct Objects):**

- Case $1$: Exactly $4$ Dogs $( C_1D_1D_2D_3D_4C_2 )$

$ \qquad$ Choose $4$ dogs, permute them, surrounded by $2$ cats (to ensure exactly $4$), permute these $2$ cats, then permute the leftover $\qquad$ $6$ dogs and cats. Divide by the total number of circular permutations of all $12$ animals.

$$\dfrac{{6\choose4} \cdot 4! \cdot {6\choose2} \cdot 2! \cdot 6!}{11!}$$

- Case $2$: Exactly $5$ Dogs $( C_1D_1D_2D_3D_4D_5C_2 )$
  $$\dfrac{{6\choose5} \cdot 5! \cdot {6\choose2} \cdot 2! \cdot 5!}{11!}$$
- Case $3$: All 6 Dogs together $( D_1D_2D_3D_4D_5D_6 )$
  $$\dfrac{{6\choose6} \cdot 6!  \cdot 6!}{11!}$$

$\quad$Adding all the three, the final answer is that P(at least $4$ dogs together) = $\dfrac3{11}$.

**Actual Answer (Indistinguishable Objects):**

- Please refer to the [answer by @user317176](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4752017/1213925) in the original post.

---

How and Why are the two answers coming out to be the same?

> In general, what are the conditions by which the probability of a certain event occuring is independent of whether the objects are distinct or indistinguishable?

---

One final follow up: The following method surprisingly also leads to the correct answer. Is there a reasoning to explain this weird approach?

$\quad$ $ \dfrac {{6 \choose 4} \cdot 4! \cdot 9!}{12!} = \dfrac{3}{11}$