Why is the probability of drawing exactly one bad product in a sequence of three draws the same, regardless of which draw is the bad product?

A box contains $10$ good products and $5$ bad products. Draw at once $3$ random products from the box. What is the probability of drawing exactly $2$ good products?

Certainly, the answer is $\dfrac{\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{15}{3}}.$
If we draw one product at a time instead of three products at once, the answer should be the same and equal to the sum of the probabilities of drawing the bad product the first time, the second time, and the third time.
The first time: $\dfrac{5}{15}\cdot\dfrac{10}{14}\cdot\dfrac{9}{13}$
The second time:$\dfrac{10}{15}\cdot\dfrac{5}{14}\cdot\dfrac{9}{13}$
The third time: $\dfrac{10}{15}\cdot\dfrac{9}{14}\cdot\dfrac{5}{13}$
I suspect that the $3$ probabilities are equal (and indeed they are as the nominator = denominator for all terms), but I can't seem to understand why it turns out this way. Is there an intuitive explanation for why they must be equal?
Thank you!

Because given that there are two good and one bad product, the probability of the bad product coming in each of the draws is uniformly distributed

I asked a similar question but on different lines. In my question, the probability was independent of whether the objects were distinct or not. It still hasn't been answered. Check it out if you'd want: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792489/probability-independent-of-distinction-between-objects

@stochs How does that explain why the probability of picking all at once is the same as the probability of picking one by one?

@stochsThat makes sense! Thanks!

@DevanshAgarwal In this case the event for which the probability is being calculated is the same namely "probability of drawing exactly 2
good products"

@DevanshAgarwal I'm not sure if this works, but here's my thought: Let $S$ be "draw in succession," $O$ be "drawing at once" and $R$ be "draw $2$ good items and $1$ bad item." We wish to show that $P(R|S) = P(R|O).$ We have:
$P(R|S) = \dfrac{P(R∩S)}{P(S)}$
. Also, $P(S) = 1$ since $S$ is simply a method being considered, while $P(R∩S) = $ the probability that we select $2$ good items and $1$ bad item in these $3$ successive draws $=$ the probability that we select $2$ good items and $1$ bad item in one simultaneous draw of $3$ items $= P(R|O) \implies P(R|S) = P(R|O)$
